# How to route to another component and replace current component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a messaging app using ReactJS and MaterialUI for theming. I have an Appbar and a permanent drawer, and want to render my inbox, sent and new message components in the remaining area.

I use routes in the inbox and sent components' parent component to change the url when these components are rendered (/messages/inbox and /messages/sent). Now, I want to render the new message component when the "+" button in inbox or sent components are clicked, un-render the current component, and change the url to be /messages/new.

I know that I can conditionally render the NewMessage Component by setting a boolean state variable, but that still doesn't change the url.

I not sure how to go about doing this, and would like some advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Link component from react-router-dom that would bring them to the /messages/new component. You can learn more about it [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `<Link to ="/path here" > + </Link>`

or

you can programmatically navigate using `this.props.history.push("/path")` that gets passed from histroy props  [check here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)  when you do the click event (Note to import withRouter if the prop's aren't available [withRouter info here)](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)

and add your `<Route path =""  component={}/>` respectively

hope this helps ..

Answer (score 0):

K guys, I figured it out. I had a Navigation component file containing my appbar and drawer, which had Routes to my inbox and sent components. in my inbox/sent components, I wanted to have a link to a NewMessage component that would replace the current inbox/sent component. I found out that if I add a Route to NewMessage in my Navigation component, `<Route exact path="/messages/new" component={NewMessage} />`, and in my inbox/sent component, add something like:

```
<Fab color="primary" label="New" component={Link} to="/messages/new">
  <AddIcon />
</Fab>
```

It routes fine. Maybe I still haven't understood the parent/child relationship in ReactJS, but I was able to solve my issue doing this.

Thank you everyone for your time.